# Baseball average with chart/bar graph outputted

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that calculates the baseball player averages , and keeps asking until it reaches the user set amount of players. I have to then output the data into a graph that has the players batting average with a * marking where it falls into.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BattingInfo
{
        public:
                char fname[25];
                char lname[25];
                float hits;
                float battimes;
                float games;
                float tgames;
                float average;
                float averaget;
                float gaverage;

};

bool getd(BattingInfo& bi);
void displayd(BattingInfo& bi);

int main()
{
        int players;
    BattingInfo bi[9999];
    cout <<"Please input the number of players:\n";
        cin >> players;

        int index;
    index = 0;

    while (getd(bi[index])&& index < players - 1)
    {
        index++;
    }

        cout << "\n\nData Entries: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        displayd(bi[i]);
    }
}

bool getd(BattingInfo& bi)
        {       cout <<"Please input the Players first name:\n";
                cin >> bi.fname;
                cout <<"Please input the Players last name:\n";
                cin >> bi.lname;
                cout << "Please input the number of number of successful hits of the player.\n";
                cin >> bi.hits;
                cout << "Please input the numer of times at bat.\n";
                cin >> bi.battimes;
                cout << "Please input the number of games the player participated in.\n";
                cin >> bi.games;
                cout <<"Please input the total numer of games the player could have batted in.\n";
                cin >> bi.tgames;

        system("cls");

                return true;
        }

void displayd(BattingInfo& bi)
        {
                bi.average = bi.hits/bi.battimes;
                bi.gaverage = bi.games/bi.tgames;
                bi.averaget = bi.average*bi.gaverage;
        cout <<"Batting Average: " << bi.averaget << endl;
        cout << ".000 - .099";
        if (bi.averaget > .0 && bi.averaget < .1)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.100 - .199";
        if (bi.averaget > .099 && bi.averaget < .2)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.200 - .299";
        if (bi.averaget > .199 && bi.averaget < .3)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.300 - .399";
        if (bi.averaget > .299 && bi.averaget < .4)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.400 - .499";
        if (bi.averaget > .399 && bi.averaget < .5)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.500 - .599";
        if (bi.averaget > .499 && bi.averaget < .6)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.600 - .699";
        if (bi.averaget > .599 && bi.averaget < .7)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.700 - .799";
        if (bi.averaget > .699 && bi.averaget < .8)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.800 - .899";
        if (bi.averaget > .799 && bi.averaget < .9)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n.000 - .999";
        if (bi.averaget > .899 && bi.averaget < .1)
        { cout << "*";}
        cout << "\n1";
        if (bi.averaget > .999)
        { cout << "*\n";}
        system("\nPAUSE");
        system("cls");
        }
```

It kind of works, but the graph is outputted for each player (with only 1 players average on it), I need it to output for the whole team on one graph. Im not sure how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Ok sorry about that Christian. Thanks for replying. I have done research and can not find how to properly make the graph. If you run the program you will see that it asks user how many players they want to calculate the average for. Then get the required information. After that it does make the graph correctly, but only for each player separately. I need it to output one graph with the whole team. Im not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: How are you supposed to make the graph? Should you be using a GUI or are you supposed to make a graph using only a basic text window?

Comment: @David I am suppose to just make it in a basic text window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic graph that displays values from left to right. You could use this as a base and alter it to display your data. If this isn't what you are looking for, you might want to use a proper GUI library.

Note my use of vector<> instead of arrays. Don't use arrays unless you have to. Use vector.

I'm guessing this might be a school project, so finishing this yourself would probably be best.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void display_as_graph(vector<int>& numbers)
{
    char space = ' ';
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int num_spaces = 0; num_spaces < numbers[i]; num_spaces++)
        {
            cout << space;
        }
        cout << "x\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.push_back(4);
    numbers.push_back(6);
    numbers.push_back(8);
    numbers.push_back(3);

    display_as_graph(numbers);

    string wait;
    cin >> wait;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but Im not sure if that is exactly how I am suppose to do it. I am suppose to output something like

Brandon Smith
Batting Average: .833

John Smith
Batting Average: .933

.000 - .099
.100 - .199
.200 - .299
.300 - .399
.400 - .499
.500 - .599
.600 - .699
.700 - .799
.800 - .899*
.000 - .999*
1

Then output a "*" each time the average falls in between one of those number sets. So like if two players have an average of .833 , 2 asterisk would print after .800 - .899.

Comment: That's exactly right. You could dynamically make the range based on all the entries used, but that's probably a lot more work. I would suggest just going for .300-.350, .350-.400 etc. If you haven't been taught or aren't expected to teach yourself how to output real graphics, I would imagine that would be an acceptable solution.