# Baseball Batting Average Program

Tags: c++

I need help with a program for school.  We had to write a program that asks the user for information about a baseball player.  We need to calculate the players batting average with their games played, number of times at bat and number of hits.  I am running into an issue where my computation for the average is outputting a set number and not performing any computations.  I am entering whole integers for all the variables that are used for calculation.  So i would input numbers like 1, 4 , 10 etc...  As the program stands the value my formula is setting itself equal to is 15903.876.  All of my variables used for the average formula are declared as integers and the batting average itself is declared as a double.  I have done some debugging my self and found that the computation messes up when it divides the number of times at bat by the number of hits.  If anyone could help me figure out the issue i would appreciate it.

```
//libaries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

class battingAverage
{
public:

  string pName;
  int nBats;
  int tHits;
  int gPlayed;
  int gcalled;
  double average;
  double average1;
  double playeraverage;

};

int main()
{
   string numberPlayers;
  int nplayers;
 //enters the number of players the user wants to enter data for
 cout << "Enter the number of players you want to enter data for: ";
 cin >> numberPlayers;
 cout << endl;

//converts the value of numberPlayers to nplayers
istringstream convert(numberPlayers);

//sets integer nplayers equal to the value of the string numberPlayers
if(! (istringstream(numberPlayers) >> nplayers) )
{
    nplayers = 0;
}

cout << "This program calculates the batting average of baseball players.\nYou may enter data for " << nplayers << " players." << endl;

battingAverage ba[nplayers];

int index = 0;

//while statement to get data
while(index < nplayers)
{
  cout << "Enter the players last name: " << endl;
  cin >> ba[index].pName;

  cout << "Enter the number of games the player played: " << endl;
  cin >> ba[index].gPlayed;
  cout << ba[index].gPlayed << endl;

  cout << "Enter the number of games the player was called in for: " << endl;
  cin >> ba[index].gcalled;
  cout << ba[index].gcalled << endl;

  cout << "Enter the number of times the player was at bat: " << endl;
  cin >> ba[index].nBats;
  cout << ba[index].nBats << endl;

  cout << "Enter the number of time the player hit: " << endl;
  cin >> ba[index].tHits;
  cout << ba[index].tHits << endl;

  if(ba[index].tHits > ba[index].nBats)
  {
    cout << "Enter a valid value for the number of times the player hit: ";
    cin >> ba[index].tHits;
  }

  cout << endl;
  index++;

}

//rounds average to 3 decimal places
cout << fixed << setprecision( 3 );
//average formula
ba[index].playeraverage = (ba[index].nBats / ba[index].tHits) * (ba[index].gPlayed / ba[index].gcalled);//error
cout << ba[index].playeraverage << endl << endl;//just temp line to check calculation of average.

ba[index].average = .000;
ba[index].average1 = .099;

 while(ba[index].average < 1 && ba[index].average1 < .899)
{
    ba[index].average +=.100;
    ba[index].average1 += .1;
    //prints chart
    cout << setprecision( 1 ) << ba[index].average  << "00" << setprecision( 3 ) << setw(12) << ba[index].average1 << endl;
    }

cout << "1.000" << setw(12) << "1.000" << endl;

//version of system pause
cout << "\nPress enter to continue...";
cin.sync();
cin.ignore();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Describe what a "weird number" is.  What input did you give your program? what output did you expect?

Comment: You're doing integer division.  Do floating point, and you'll be fine.  In integer division, smaller_number / larger_number always = 0.  In other words, if you're not batting 1000, you're batting 0.  :-)

Comment: Public data, hell yeah!

Comment: [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719466/baseball-average-with-chart-bar-graph-outputted) i got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value of index is wrong during the calculations.

I found this as soon as I put your code in a debugger and stepped through it, something you ***really*** should have done yourself.

You start with `int index = 0;`, and increment it as the user puts in each player's data.
At the end of the input-loop, index is now the same as the number of players.
*(eg. if you had 5 players, index is now 5, and the player data is stored in `ba[0]`, `ba[1]`, `ba[2]`, `ba[3]`, and `ba[4]`)*

Note that at this point `ba[5]` is **NOT** valid data.  But that is exactly where `ba[index]` is!

You do all your calculations on `ba[index]`, which is invalid data, and you wonder why you get meaningless results?

**I recommend you set index back to 0 before starting your calculations, and make another loop that does the necessary calculations for each player 0...4.**

Comment: Ok thank you that fixed it and what debugger would you recommend?

Comment: Really depends on your platform.  On Windows, use the Visual Studio built-in debugger.   On Linux, GDB and/or Eclipse are common and well documented.   I don't know Apple very well.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
ba[index].playeraverage = (ba[index].nBats / ba[index].tHits) * (ba[index].gPlayed / ba[index].gcalled);//error
```

You have this expression:

```
(ba[index].nBats / ba[index].tHits)
```

Because both `nBats` and `tHits` are integers, you're using only integer math.
The answer will be an integer.

***For example:***
`nBats = 10` & `tHits = 3`, you'd expect the expression to be `3.333`.
But it would only be `3`

To fix this, I recommend changing to:

```
((double)ba[index].nBats / ba[index].tHits)
```

Same thing again with the expression about `gPlayed` and `gcalled`.

Comment: Ok i tried that and the output doesn't change.  Could i need a math library?  If not any other thoughts?

Comment: You have not clarified your question.  You said your program responds with a "weird number".  What input did you give it? What output did you expect? what output did you actually get?  (*"weird number"* is not at all precise)

Comment: Sorry,I am looking for a 3 decimal place number.  I am entering whole numbers then performing division on them.  The output is 15903.876.  But i am looking for a range of .100 through .999. Any ideas?

Comment: Why won't you answer the simple question:  "What input did you give your program?" That is a pretty basic debugging question, and you keep refusing to answer it. Go edit your actual question to include this kind of information. (information that you *really* should have included in the first place.)

Comment: **No, it is not.**  For anyone to help you, we want to *reproduce* the same problem you are seeing. We want the ***same input*** you are using.   Statements like *"I am entering whole integers for all the variables"* and *"i would input numbers like..."* are not helpful.   We want ***exact*** input, your expected result for that input, and the output you actually got.